# android ui design varies for the same dimensions but the screen sizes are different which devices are having hardware menu button

Tags: android, android-layout

If device has hardware menu button then the layout design is corrupted.I'm having a layout which is fit for xxxhdpi devices.It was looking good in nexus6 but when I'm checking it in samsung galaxy note 4 which is also xxxhdpi device the screen design was corrupted.I observed that the samsung devices having hardware menu button where as nexus6 having the hardware menu button on the screen.So the height of the layout is vary.Can you please let me know how to handle this situation.

[image: Note 4] [image: Nexus 6]

Comment: could you post screenshots from both the devices?

Comment: I have shared the screen shots.Please checkt it

Comment: to give a comprehensive answer I'd need screenshots of both the devices to evaluate the difference between expected and actual layouts. Also I'll need to read the layout resource files to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have attached the screenshots already the galaxy note4 which is the actual expected design and the nexus6 which is having different look than the expected result.These both devices are xxxhdpi and the dimensions are  1440x2560

Answer (score 1):

this is resolution and density problem. I had the same problem and I solved it by adjusting the text-size and padding according to my device with button on screen and things automatically got fixed on the other device with same screen-size.
First create layout file for 360 dip(layout-sw360 dip) and then adjust layout for your nexus 6.This problem will be resolved.

Comment: if I'm creating layout-sw360dp folder some devices from xxxhdpi and xxdpi are taking values from sw360dp folder which corrupts the design.My problem is some devices are having hardware back button and home button inside the screen where as samsung and htc devices are having those buttons on the device not on the screen which makes some difference in the screen sizes which are related to same dimensions.

Comment: @krishna, I know this is dimension problem,for that i say minimize the dimensions like test size. adjust the layout..